# MySQL Connector Unhandled Expection in Debug Mode

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

I have tried to establish a connection to a MySQL database using ConnectorC++.
In release mode everything works without any problems, but when I try it in debug mode I get the "catch (std::exception& e)" block, I only get the following error message: bad allocation

The Unhandled Expection error is triggered here: con = driver->connect("127.0.0.1:3308", "test", "test");

What could be the reason for this?

The Code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jdbc/mysql_connection.h>
#include <jdbc/mysql_driver.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver* driver;
    sql::Connection* con;

    try 
    {
        driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error initializing the MySQL driver: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1; // Exit the program
    }

    try 
    {

        std::cout << "start with connect" << std::endl;
        // Replace 'localhost', 'root', 'password' and 'database' with your own values
        con = driver->connect("127.0.0.1:3308", "test", "test");
        std::cout << "connect start" << std::endl;

        if (!con)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error when connecting to the MySQL database." << std::endl;
            return 1; // Exit the program
        }

        // Select the database
        con->setSchema("test");

        std::cout << "Connection to the MySQL database established." << std::endl;


        // Close the connection when it is no longer needed
        delete con;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException& e) 
    {
        std::cerr << "MySQL-Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) 
    {
        std::cerr << "General error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1; // Exit the program
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        std::cerr << "Unknown error occurred" << std::endl;
        return 1; // Exit the program
    }
}
```

I also tried to download the debug files from ConnectorC++ and integrate them in debug mode. But without any difference.

I am using version 8.2 of ConnectorC++

Comment: Do you run it on Windows? Perhaps you run your app with a wrong MySQL DLL runtime: MT, MTd, MD, MDd.

Comment: It does not look like a bug from the lib according to both the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-connect-options.html) and the code, the connect method is as follows [connect impl](https://github.com/anhstudios/mysql-connector-cpp/blob/3ff636efb815742657c2de90c71883389945d5fe/driver/mysql_driver.cpp#L119C25-L119C25), calling behind the scenes the [MySQL_Connection constructor](https://github.com/anhstudios/mysql-connector-cpp/blob/3ff636efb815742657c2de90c71883389945d5fe/driver/mysql_connection.cpp#L104C53-L104C53)

Comment: ***I only get the following error message: bad allocation*** A bad allocation exception could definitely be the case @273K mentioned. Mixing debug and release could be onre reason for this. Make sure you use debug libraries for debug configuration and release libraries for release configuration.

Comment: I use "mysql-connector-c++-8.2.0-winx64-debug" for the debug mode and have set the include and lib paths accordingly. For release mode I use "mysql-connector-c++-8.2.0-winx64"
I use windows 10.
For Debug I have set the path as follows "...\lib64\vs14\debug" and as Additional Dependencies I have entered "mysqlcppconn.lib".

Comment: Perfect time to learn how to use your [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while inspecting the stack trace (program flow), variable values etc, set breakpoints at interesting locations (like when an exception is thrown) and more. You can also use tools like `address sanitizer`, `memory sanitizer`, `undefined-behaviour sanitizer` & `thread sanitizer` (look them up via a search engine) to see if they can pinpoint the cause of the problem (they can be *quite* efficient at that).